# .NET 5.0 WinForms Button_Click event code not running & multiple issues

Tags: vb.net, .net-5

### Issue

I'm trying to Debug an application form with buttons. Usually when we double click the button, the source window shows up with the click event for that button. However, in the latest version of .NET 5.0 release, there are a lot of things not working properly.

The following are multiple issues I'm facing that usually are not there and there is no explanation on Microsoft's Blog or MSDN about these issues:

1. When I'm adding the source-code to any button_click event, nothing is hapenning after build and debug! I tried to make it work but to no effort.
2. After renaming control(s) on the form, the project needs a complete rebuild to change the names of the controls in Designer.vb file. This used to be automatic in VB prior to .NET 5.0
3. *Application.Designer.vb* randonly desides to default the `Me.MainForm = Global.<ProjectNameHere>.<FormNameHere>` to `Me.MainForm = Global.<ProjectNameHere>.Form1` & then throws an error that Form1 is not found. Why the hell this extra work? VB used to set this automatically.

### Code: Button Click Events

```
Public Class MainWindow
    Private Sub Btn_Exit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn_MaxMin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        Else
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Btn_Minimize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    End Sub
End Class
```

I tried Debugging and click events don't respond. I tried to rebuild solution and it doesn't work. I tried adding Refresh() after each line of code and doesn't work. I rechecked designer.vb and everything else and it doesn't work.

.NET 5.0 is broken when using Visual Basic WinForms. The code intellisense has become slow. Everything is slow and not working.

### System Information

Product Version: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.0

DotNET Framework: 5.0 (Released on 11 November 2020)

Operating System: Windows 10 20H2

**Please help me fix these issues. No code provided because I don't know how will other devs reproduce these issues. I cannot find any similar problems in SO or anywhere else. I can't find any problem when using .NET 4.8 or other .NET versions other than 5.0 with WinForms and VB**.

Comment: You need to ask just one question in each thread. SO is designed in such a way that you should be able to accept an answer as a solution to your question. No one should have to answer multiple questions in order to provide a complete answer. Please take the site tour, which you should have done when prompted, and spend some time in the Help Center to learn how the site works.

Comment: It's highly likely that there will be early bugs in .NET 5.0 and supporting technologies. Some may be widespread and some may affect you but not others and could perhaps be fixed with a repair of VS. You should also expect the VB support to be a much lower priority for Microsoft than C# is. WinForms support in .NET Core is also fairly new for any language. To be frank, I'd probably stay away from .NET 5.0 for VB WinForms apps for a while yet.

Comment: Addressing your first question, which is the only one that should be asked here, I'm not sure why it has happened but your methods have no `Handles` clauses on them so they are not handling any events. Create a similar form and create a similar event handler in .NET Framework 4.8 and see the difference.

Comment: FYI, I just created a new .NET 5 VB WiinForms app, added a `Button` and created a `Click` event handler. It worked as expected, including a `Handles` clause. Note that if you were to cut (not copy) and paste your controls then that would remove the `Handles` clauses. If they just weren't added in the first place then there's something wrong with your IDE that isn't affecting mine, so I'd suggest a repair.

Comment: @jmcilhinney You are right. There is something wrong with my IDE. I uninstalled .NET 5 and repaired IDE. Seems that when we double click the button on designer, the handles clause was not automatically included in the code (which as a vb developer i'm used to IDE automagically using appropriate clauses and attributes). However, as I have noticed, the other problems still remain and now I'm sure that VB has not recieved the attention in this framework upgrade. A lot of things that were quite automatic and simple to do in VB are requiring me to work it up like a C# project.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I would rather use C# now instead of VB when migrating old projects. I had contacted the framework and .netcore dev team at microsoft recently and they indirectly told me that there won't be updates for vb because " it is a complete language and does not require updates, features, or fixes ". With this response I'm sure they will plan discontinue vb after 5-6 years. If not, developers like me are already shifting the codebase to c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your button click event handler code, I see that there is no `Handles Button1.Click`.

In order for the code to run, it must be associated with the event by doing:

```
Private Sub Btn_Exit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

Another option is:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    AddHandler btnExit.Click, AddressOf Btn_Exit_Click        'run this somewhere when the form loads
End Sub

Private Sub Btn_Exit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

If this is helpful, great. If not, provide more of your code so we can see what's all happening.

Regards